# Parâmetro na função que requer o objeto da mesma classe, gera erro 'Python NameError'. Como proceder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

O código abaixo gera o erro `NameError: name 'Matrix' is not defined`. Mas está definido! Na própria classe! Isso é um problema da linguagem? Ou eu não estou enxergando alguma coisa?

```
class Matrix:

    def mult(self, matrix:Matrix) -> Matrix: # <-- gerando erro aqui
        pass
```

Comment: Se a anotação de tipo está atrapalhando, não use haha xD

Comment: @Woss sim! Mudei o modelo inclusive! Obrigado.